# How to convert string which contains date in format @"MM/dd/YYYY h:mm a" to UTC number of seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

If I get string date in format `@"MM/dd/YYYY h:mm a"` and I have timezone of date(string date), how can I convert this to UTC number ?

Comment: What do you mean by "timezone of date(string date)" ? Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: r u looking smthing similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615833/objective-c-setting-nsdate-to-current-utc)

Comment: Read the spec for NSDate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    NSString *dateString = @"03/23/2012 09:17 PM";
    //It is assumed that the time in dateString wrt local time zone
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a"];

    NSDate*date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSTimeInterval timeInSeconds = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```