# Set time 00:00:00 in NSDate when timezone is not Local

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, ios9

I am working on Application which has users in different countries. for example, India and US.

I want NSDate with out time in all case in any timezone.

For example, 2016-03-01 will be remain same in both timezones 2016-03-01 00:00:00 +0000.

I am using

```
NSDate* dateOnly = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateBySettingHour:0 minute:0 second:0 ofDate:[NSDate date] options:NSCalendarMatchLast];
```

Still I am getting this:
2016-04-21 05:00:00 +0000

I need 2016-04-21 00:00:00 +0000

Please suggest proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This one should work

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateDormatter stringFromDate:dateOnly]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm";

NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:gmt];
NSString *timeStamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Try above line of code. Hope it will help you.

Comment: I need NSDate, not NSString.

Comment: you can convert date to string

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

> NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
>   [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];

[hope help you this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615833/objective-c-setting-nsdate-to-current-utc)