# How to get the right date format?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdateformatter, nsdatepicker

In cocoa, I have given a textual NSDatePicker and a disclosure (for displaying graphical date and time pop over) in GUI. When i select a date and time, in text field i'm getting the correct date and time in the format(dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm). But when I try to get the textfield value in console I'm getting in yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss 0000+. moreover the time is 5:30 hrs less. i want in dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm format only with the correct timings.

Comment: When putting the date value in the text field, how are you transforming your `NSDate` to `NSString`?

Comment: Please provide code snippets.

Comment: I tried with NSDate and used stringFromDate.

Comment: @property (retain)NSDate *fromDate;


        NSLog(@"%@",_fromDate);
        NSDateFormatter *projectFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [projectFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm"];
         NSString *createdDateStr = [projectFormat   stringFromDate:_fromDate]; 
         NSLog(@" der %@",createdDateStr);                  It is  in stringFromDate. But i need it in dateFrom String

Comment: Printing out a `NSDate` object will always format it default way, in GMT (+0), which is what you're doing in `NSLog(@"%@",_fromDate); `.  Is that your problem, in that you want those dates to display with a certain time zone and format?  (Which you're doing in the second NSLog you're using, so, I'm confused I guess...)

Comment: You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8866731/928963

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting date from \[NSDate date\] off by a few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours)