# NSDateFormatter return Date in GMT specific timezone

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nstimezone

I want to get the date and time in a specific time zone. I am getting most of the things right but just at the end when i get the date from `NSString` using `NSDateFormatter` method it returns me the date in the `GMT` specific time zone. The method `[formatter stringFromDate:gmtDate];` return me the expected date and time. The problem happen when i get the date from the string i-e when i execute this method `self.localTime = [formatter dateFromString:str];`. `self.localTime` is a `NSDate` property in my class.

So when i print the `str` it gives me the date and time in that specific time zone which is represented as `self.timeZoneID`, which is also a `property` on my class

```
        NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:self.timeZoneID]];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
        NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:gmtDate];
        NSLog(@"Date string : %@", str);
        self.localTime = [formatter dateFromString:str];
```

Any idea that what could be the reason that i am getting the right string output but when i assign it to my `property` `localTime` it give me the time in `GMT`

Comment: An NSDate object is GMT time.  You can't change that (without breaking some rules) and you shouldn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set NSDate TimeZone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866515/set-nsdate-timezone)

Answer (score 0):

Reason is that NSDate have a default time zone that is GMT for consideration and when a user wants to have time specific for some time zone then NSDateFormatter provides way to set specific time zone which you are using for gmtDate object and not for self.localTime(this is taking GMT ,default time zone).

Comment: So how to do this... i mean self.localTime = [NSDate date]; and then self.localTime = [formatter dateFromString:[formatter stringFromDate:self.localTime]]; i have tried this, this is also not working....

Comment: What exactly your trying to achieve ?!

Comment: I want to get the NSDate in some specific time zone. I want NSDate object not NSString object.

Comment: For specific time zone u need to apply formatter and then use the string which u get as in nsdate it takes GMT as default. Thats why nsdateformatter is there to get time as per our location time zone or in case if you want to show time according to other time zone. So better save str after using formatter. Also simply check nsdate time and GMT time(on google) then you do get it.