# Convert timestamp into NSDate

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I am parsing a JSON file which contains a timestamp. I want to convert this timestamp into an NSDate.

My code :

```
NSString *depart=[alternates valueForKey:@"startTime"];
NSTimeInterval intervaldep=[depart doubleValue];

NSDate *myDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:intervaldep];
```

But I am getting wrong date, e.g.: `44135-04-01 03:20:00 +0000` for time stamp `1330606668000`.
If any one has any idea please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your timestamp contains a value that is a correct time interval?

Comment: I cant say. bcoz i am parsing it from json file.

Comment: What time is `1330606668000` supposed to be? is it `Thu Mar 01 13:57:48 +0100 2012`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your timestamp contains milliseconds, just divide your timestamp by 1000 (i.e. trim the last three zeros) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the NSTimeZone to your NSDate, by default the dates are in GMT0

You can check the syntax here:

[Convert UTC NSDate to local Timezone Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c)