# Get time without time portion or timezone difference

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm a iOS developer of the iWorld.
I've developed several iPhone/iPad apps before.
I couldn't get correct time information on iPhone several times. I think that is due to localization.

For example, I have code to get the time-truncated today. (ex : "05-04-2012 00:00:00")
But that code always return 8 hours ago to that I've expected. (ex : "05-03-2012 16:00:00)
The code that I've worked are as following.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
today = [calender dateFromComponents:components];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *todayString = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"Today is %@", todayString);
```

I'd like to hear from you to resolve this problem.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: So what time do you expect; localtime or UTC?

Comment: I'd like to know to know the correct midnight time. Because I have to compare date against database date. For example, I have to find the record for today those are between 05-04-2012 00:00:00 and 05-05-2012 00:00:00 for just today.

Comment: So do you want localtime or UTC?

Comment: I'd like to base on UTC.

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to base on local time.

Comment: This might do it then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c

Comment: Thanks, trojanfoe. And I've found some useful things on SO just now. I've found "today = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that code that calculates correct midnight time.
Now I find that following code logs "Today is 05-07-2012 00:00:00" rather than "05-06-2012 16:00:00"

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calender = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
today = [calender dateFromComponents:components];

today = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:[[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss"];
NSString *todayString = [formatter stringFromDate:today];
NSLog(@"Today is %@", todayString);
```

Thanks for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Set timezone to UTC

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
```

Comment: He wants local time so should be using [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]