# iOS setting ekevent start time with local time zone

Tags: ios, eventkit, ekevent

In my iOS application, I'm showing date picker through which user can select at what time they want to select to store the event in calendar. i am using event kit for this.
This is working fine. But the problem is that its creating the even in GMT time zone. How can I create an event in calendar according to local time.

Comment: I found the solution from the URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:
We don't have to convert data to local time zone. We've to set the start date in GMT time zone and event kit will handle the conversion to local time zone and show it.

Comment: hi, i am facing the same issue, i am adding the time in GMT but in iCal its showing in PDT time..can u please help me fix this?