# How to convert NSDate into UTC format in iPhone

Tags: iphone, time, sdk, nsdate

I need to convert current date into UTC format, i have done the following and got the correct UTC date, below is my source code

```
NSDate *currDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currDate];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

I am getting date in this format 2013-05-01 23:11:02 GMT only i want UTC name instead on GMT what conversion do i need to do for this.

Comment: try this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your just concerned with the text than do a string replace:

```
 NSString *convString = [dateString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"GMT" withString:@"UTC"];
```