# How to specify timezone for dates in parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, timezone

When updating or creating objects in my database, I need to specify the timezone. How can this be achieved in parse dot com?

Is there any global setting for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the REST APIs, there is no local time zone support.

[Parse.com uses UTC for all timestamps](https://www.parse.com/questions/timezone-for-pfobjects), so you'll have to locally convert the time between the time zone in question and UTC before passing it to its APIs or - the other way - after getting it from the API before presenting it to the user.

Comment: The Difference Between GMT and UTC: http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html

Comment: Convert UTC to local time in objective C: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564769/convert-utc-to-local-time-in-objective-c

Comment: Is this still the case? Because according to Parse's [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide#push-notifications-local-push-scheduling), it seems to be supported (I haven't been able to get it to work though).