# Converting UTC date format to local nsdate

Tags: ios, swift, date, timezone, nsdate

I am getting from my server a string date in UTC time zone and I need to convert it to the local time zone.

MY CODE:

```
let utcTime = "2015-04-01T11:42:00.269Z"    
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(utcTime)
println("utc: \(utcTime), date: \(date)")
```

this prints -

utc: 2015-04-01T11:42:00.269Z, date: Optional(2015-04-01 11:42:00 +0000)

if I remove

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
```

it prints

utc: 2015-04-01T11:42:00.269Z, date: Optional(2015-04-01 08:42:00 +0000)

my local time zone is UTC +3 
and in the first option I get UTC
in the second option I get UTC -3

I should get

utc: 2015-04-01T11:42:00.269Z, date: Optional(2015-04-01 14:42:00 +0000)

So how do I convert the UTC date format to local time?

Comment: Have you tried formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

Comment: yes, i get UTC -3 ... utc: 2015-04-01T11:42:00.269Z, date: Optional(2015-04-01 08:42:00 +0000)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564769/convert-utc-to-local-time-in-objective-c

Comment: @ilan I am also facing the same issue in swift. Could you please help me in this.

Comment: @Rakesh check out the answers below, they worked for me.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Something along the following worked for me in Objective-C :

```
// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"]; 
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2015-04-01T11:42:00"]; // create date from string

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *timestamp = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

I keep these two websites handy for converting different time formats:
http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

http://benscheirman.com/2010/06/dealing-with-dates-time-zones-in-objective-c/

In Swift it will be:

```
// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone?
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2015-04-01T11:42:00")// create   date from string

        // change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

Comment: In swift3, the equivalent will be:
```dateFormatter.timezone = TimeZone.current```

Comment: let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-04-01T11:42:00") 
This assign nil to date when I set 12 hrs time format in device settings.

Comment: when You convert back to date it gives again in UTC.

Answer (score 70):

Try this Swift extension

**Swift 4**: UTC/GMT ⟺ Local (Current/System)

```
extension Date {

    // Convert local time to UTC (or GMT)
    func toGlobalTime() -> Date {
        let timezone = TimeZone.current
        let seconds = -TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: self))
        return Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: self)
    }

    // Convert UTC (or GMT) to local time
    func toLocalTime() -> Date {
        let timezone = TimeZone.current
        let seconds = TimeInterval(timezone.secondsFromGMT(for: self))
        return Date(timeInterval: seconds, since: self)
    }

}


// Try it
let utcDate = Date().toGlobalTime()
let localDate = utcDate.toLocalTime()

print("utcDate - \(utcDate)")        //Print UTC Date
print("localDate - \(localDate)")     //Print Local Date
```

Comment: @Krunal, I like the simplicity of this, but when I run this:
`public func runDatesExample() {

    let now = Date() 
    let utcDate = now.toGlobalTime()
    let localDate = now.toLocalTime()
    
    print(now)              //prints: 2020-04-08 00:31:17 +0000. //actual GMT/UTC right now
    print("utcDate - \(utcDate)")          //prints: utcDate - 2020-04-08 06:31:17 +0000
    print("localDate - \(localDate)")     //prints: localDate - 2020-04-07 18:31:17 +0000
}
`
I would have expected `utcDate` to be the same output as `now`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: This does **NOT** return the time in the local timezone. It returns a Date object that represents a point in time with a certain offset from the current time. Then it prints that as a UTC time.
To get a string representing the time in the local time zone, use DateFormatter.

Comment: @fishinear - You are welcomed to edit and improve quality of this answer.

Comment: @Krunal There is no need to do that, there are already multiple correct answers to the question. You are welcomed to remove the answer.

Answer (score 27):

Swift version of c_rath answer:

```
// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("2015-04-01T11:42:00")

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone() 
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date!)
```

Comment: Line 5 should read: dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"  and Line 6 should read: dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()

Answer (score 9):

I had to remove both z and milli seconds from c_rath solution. Works in swift 4.

```
extension String {
    func fromUTCToLocalDateTime() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
        var formattedString = self.replacingOccurrences(of: "Z", with: "")
        if let lowerBound = formattedString.range(of: ".")?.lowerBound {
            formattedString = "\(formattedString[..<lowerBound])"
        }

        guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: formattedString) else {
            return self
        }

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 3 this works well:

```
// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2015-04-01T11:42:00")// create date from string

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, MMM d, yyyy - h:mm a"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on what others have mentioned, here is a handy `NSDate` extension in Swift

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate {
    func ToLocalStringWithFormat(dateFormat: String) -> String {
        // change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
        let timeStamp = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)

        return timeStamp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try something like:

```
extension NSDate {
    convenience init(utcDate:String, dateFormat:String="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS+00:00") {
        // 2016-06-06 00:24:21.164493+00:00
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC")

        let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(utcDate)!
        let s = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMTForDate(date)
        let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(s)

        self.init(timeInterval: timeInterval, sinceDate:date)
    }
}
```