# How can i convert string to date with some strange format

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am getting some strange date format as string from server
`2016-10-03T17:28:34.773`
Which format I need to use to convert this string to date.

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` is the format here

Comment: Most of the date formats are standard formats. you can refer them here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It's a UTC date format. There's many answers here. Here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392874/converting-utc-date-format-to-local-nsdate

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks !!! It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to get date from your string.

```
 - (NSDate *) dateFromServerAttributeDateFormat:(NSString *)dateString
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
        [dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
        if (!dateString.length){
          return nil;
          }
        else
            return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    }
```

in swift

```
   func dateFromServerString(dateString:String) -> NSDate {
    let dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormater.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
    dateFormater.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    return dateFormater.dateFromString(dateString)!
}
```

Comment: Your date format does not match the string from the question. And btw, that's Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: thanks i  will edit, and sorry I was unaware of language