# Converting calendar date to the correct date

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calendar, nsdate

I am working on an application that creates alerts with calendar. I can correctly set alarms on correct dates. For example, I set an alarm for `4th of May 2017 1 PM`.

When, I try to get the calendar event it returns me some other date in UTC.

[image]

As you can see, it returns me `10 AM` on same day with UTC. I am wondering how can I get the exact date when I try to get it from calendar.

Comment: You need to correct the timezone, perhaps setting timezone in your custom calendar may help.

Comment: This should help, you just need to convert the date to your current timezone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392874/converting-utc-date-format-to-local-nsdate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert **UTC** to **your local timezone**.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *date1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-05-04 10:00:00"];

// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSString *strCurrentLocalTimezoneDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date` always takes current time zone until we changed other.If we print the `Date` it might be showing different but actually it takes current.

Answer (score -1):

// except this code you may have to set timeZone as well.

```
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[format setDateFormat:@"MMM-dd-yyyy"];

NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

NSString *dateString = [format stringFromDate:now];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```