# Add GMT Time to a Given Date Time(from server) in ios

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, gmt

I have a date like "2017-07-31T05:12:17.36" from server (Server time in another country). I need to add GMT+5:30 to this date to make it the time in INDIA. Please help.

Please use the the above date string in answers.

Also Please use swift

Comment: If India is your local time zone look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392874/converting-utc-date-format-to-local-nsdate)

Comment: refers https://stackoverflow.com/a/42811162/7334409

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rfcDateFormatter : DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS"
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")
    return formatter
}

var localDateFormatter : DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss.SS"
    return formatter
}

let date = rfcDateFormatter.date(from: "2017-07-31T05:12:17.36")
let localDate = localDateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

I hope it helps you.