# Not able to convert UTC time

Tags: ios, swift, utc

I'm getting this UTC time in string format from the server..`"2019-12-18T10:58:40Z"`

Now I want to convert it into local time. For that I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29392874/converting-utc-date-format-to-local-nsdate) link. But it's not working..

What I wanted to achieve was to convert UTC time to local time and set a timer based on that time.

This is what I've tried..

```
var utcTime = "\(json["expirationDate"]!)"

self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
let date = self.dateFormatter.date(from: utcTime)
let utcDate = date?.toGlobalTime()
let localDate = utcDate?.toLocalTime()
```

But I'm getting nil values for the dates..

Answer (score 0):

You don't have milliseconds in your UTC date string example. Your date format should be

```
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

Comment: Thanks @Pancho. Now when I print `localDate`, I get `Optional(2019-12-18 05:48:06 +0000)`. So does  this mean the time is 5:48 PM..?

Comment: Should mean AM not PM, but you can re-format that again and get whatever date format you need to fit your purpose. This is just the console printing the date object for you. Not sure what date format is used for that.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change this format from 
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"**you have to

```
let utcTime = "2019-12-18T10:58:40Z"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter.init()
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: utcTime)
print(date)
```