# How to convert Indian time to other time based on country?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nstimezone

I am getting Indian time from server when user opens app.
 But If user opens my app from other country I have to show the time based on that country.How can I solve this?

Comment: convert the received server time to UTC and then get the Local country time.

Comment: @AmitKalghatgi I tried it but I can't can you give me one example please

Answer (score 5):

Hi Please Check Code :

```
  NSDate *myDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [f setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [f setDateFormat:@"dd MMM YYY HH:mm"];

    NSArray *timeZoneNames = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
    for (NSString *name1 in timeZoneNames)
    {
        NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:name1];
        [f setTimeZone:tz];

        NSLog(@"%@ = \"%@\" = %@", [tz abbreviation], name1, [f stringFromDate:myDate]);
    }
```

And Output will show :

```
2016-07-19 14:46:18.256 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Abidjan" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.257 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Accra" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.257 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Addis_Ababa" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.258 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Algiers" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.258 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Asmara" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.259 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Bamako" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.259 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Bangui" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.260 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Banjul" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.260 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Bissau" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.260 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Blantyre" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.261 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Brazzaville" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.261 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Bujumbura" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.262 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Cairo" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.262 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Casablanca" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.272 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Ceuta" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.272 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Conakry" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.273 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Dakar" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.273 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Dar_es_Salaam" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.274 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Djibouti" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.274 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Douala" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.275 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/El_Aaiun" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.275 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Freetown" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.275 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Gaborone" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.276 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Harare" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.276 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Johannesburg" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.277 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Juba" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.277 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Kampala" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.277 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Khartoum" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.278 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Kigali" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.278 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Kinshasa" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.279 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Lagos" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.279 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Libreville" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.280 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Lome" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.280 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Luanda" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.280 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Lubumbashi" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.281 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Lusaka" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.281 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Malabo" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.282 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Maputo" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.282 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Maseru" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.282 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Mbabane" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.283 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Mogadishu" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.283 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Monrovia" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.284 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Africa/Nairobi" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.284 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Ndjamena" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.285 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Niamey" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.286 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Nouakchott" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.286 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Ouagadougou" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.287 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Porto-Novo" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.287 da[3702:334577] GMT = "Africa/Sao_Tome" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.288 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Africa/Tripoli" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.288 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Tunis" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.289 da[3702:334577] GMT+1 = "Africa/Windhoek" = 19 Jul 2016 10:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.289 da[3702:334577] HADT = "America/Adak" = 19 Jul 2016 00:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.290 da[3702:334577] AKDT = "America/Anchorage" = 19 Jul 2016 01:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.290 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Anguilla" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.291 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Antigua" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.291 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Araguaina" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.292 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.292 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Catamarca" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.292 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Cordoba" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.293 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Jujuy" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.293 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/La_Rioja" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.294 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Mendoza" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.294 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.295 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Salta" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.295 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/San_Juan" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.296 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/San_Luis" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.296 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Tucuman" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.296 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Argentina/Ushuaia" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.297 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Aruba" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.297 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Asuncion" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.298 da[3702:334577] EST = "America/Atikokan" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.298 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Bahia" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.299 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Bahia_Banderas" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.299 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Barbados" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.300 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Belem" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.300 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Belize" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.300 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Blanc-Sablon" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.301 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Boa_Vista" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.301 da[3702:334577] GMT-5 = "America/Bogota" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.302 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Boise" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.302 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Cambridge_Bay" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.303 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Campo_Grande" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.303 da[3702:334577] EST = "America/Cancun" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.303 da[3702:334577] GMT-4:30 = "America/Caracas" = 19 Jul 2016 04:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.304 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Cayenne" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.304 da[3702:334577] EST = "America/Cayman" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.305 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Chicago" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.305 da[3702:334577] GMT-6 = "America/Chihuahua" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.306 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Costa_Rica" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.306 da[3702:334577] MST = "America/Creston" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.307 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Cuiaba" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.307 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Curacao" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.308 da[3702:334577] GMT = "America/Danmarkshavn" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.308 da[3702:334577] PDT = "America/Dawson" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.325 da[3702:334577] MST = "America/Dawson_Creek" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.326 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Denver" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.326 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Detroit" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.327 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Dominica" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.327 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Edmonton" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.328 da[3702:334577] GMT-5 = "America/Eirunepe" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.328 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/El_Salvador" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.328 da[3702:334577] MST = "America/Fort_Nelson" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.329 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Fortaleza" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.329 da[3702:334577] ADT = "America/Glace_Bay" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.330 da[3702:334577] GMT-2 = "America/Godthab" = 19 Jul 2016 07:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.330 da[3702:334577] ADT = "America/Goose_Bay" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.357 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Grand_Turk" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.357 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Grenada" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.358 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Guadeloupe" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.358 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Guatemala" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.359 da[3702:334577] GMT-5 = "America/Guayaquil" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.359 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Guyana" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.360 da[3702:334577] ADT = "America/Halifax" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.360 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Havana" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.360 da[3702:334577] GMT-7 = "America/Hermosillo" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.361 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Indiana/Indianapolis" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.361 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Indiana/Knox" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.362 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Indiana/Marengo" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.362 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Indiana/Petersburg" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.362 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Indiana/Tell_City" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.363 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Indiana/Vevay" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.363 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Indiana/Vincennes" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.364 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Indiana/Winamac" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.364 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Inuvik" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.375 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Iqaluit" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.376 da[3702:334577] EST = "America/Jamaica" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.376 da[3702:334577] AKDT = "America/Juneau" = 19 Jul 2016 01:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.377 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Kentucky/Louisville" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.377 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Kentucky/Monticello" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.378 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Kralendijk" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.378 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/La_Paz" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.378 da[3702:334577] GMT-5 = "America/Lima" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.379 da[3702:334577] PDT = "America/Los_Angeles" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.379 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Lower_Princes" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.380 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Maceio" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.380 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Managua" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.381 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Manaus" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.381 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Marigot" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.381 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Martinique" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.382 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Matamoros" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.382 da[3702:334577] GMT-6 = "America/Mazatlan" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.383 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Menominee" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.383 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Merida" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.384 da[3702:334577] AKDT = "America/Metlakatla" = 19 Jul 2016 01:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.384 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Mexico_City" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.384 da[3702:334577] GMT-2 = "America/Miquelon" = 19 Jul 2016 07:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.385 da[3702:334577] ADT = "America/Moncton" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.385 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Monterrey" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.386 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Montevideo" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.387 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Montreal" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.387 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Montserrat" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.387 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Nassau" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.388 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/New_York" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.388 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Nipigon" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.389 da[3702:334577] AKDT = "America/Nome" = 19 Jul 2016 01:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.389 da[3702:334577] GMT-2 = "America/Noronha" = 19 Jul 2016 07:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.389 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/North_Dakota/Beulah" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.390 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/North_Dakota/Center" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.390 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/North_Dakota/New_Salem" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.391 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Ojinaga" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.391 da[3702:334577] EST = "America/Panama" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.391 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Pangnirtung" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.392 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Paramaribo" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.392 da[3702:334577] MST = "America/Phoenix" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.393 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Port-au-Prince" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.393 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Port_of_Spain" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.394 da[3702:334577] GMT-4 = "America/Porto_Velho" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.394 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Puerto_Rico" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.394 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Rainy_River" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.395 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Rankin_Inlet" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.395 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Recife" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.395 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Regina" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.396 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Resolute" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.396 da[3702:334577] GMT-5 = "America/Rio_Branco" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.397 da[3702:334577] GMT-7 = "America/Santa_Isabel" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.397 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Santarem" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.398 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Santiago" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.398 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Santo_Domingo" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.399 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "America/Sao_Paulo" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.399 da[3702:334577] GMT = "America/Scoresbysund" = 19 Jul 2016 09:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.399 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Shiprock" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.400 da[3702:334577] AKDT = "America/Sitka" = 19 Jul 2016 01:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.400 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/St_Barthelemy" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.401 da[3702:334577] GMT-2:30 = "America/St_Johns" = 19 Jul 2016 06:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.401 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/St_Kitts" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.401 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/St_Lucia" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.402 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/St_Thomas" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.402 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/St_Vincent" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.403 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Swift_Current" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.403 da[3702:334577] CST = "America/Tegucigalpa" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.403 da[3702:334577] ADT = "America/Thule" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.404 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Thunder_Bay" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.404 da[3702:334577] PDT = "America/Tijuana" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.404 da[3702:334577] EDT = "America/Toronto" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.405 da[3702:334577] AST = "America/Tortola" = 19 Jul 2016 05:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.405 da[3702:334577] PDT = "America/Vancouver" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.406 da[3702:334577] PDT = "America/Whitehorse" = 19 Jul 2016 02:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.406 da[3702:334577] CDT = "America/Winnipeg" = 19 Jul 2016 04:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.407 da[3702:334577] AKDT = "America/Yakutat" = 19 Jul 2016 01:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.407 da[3702:334577] MDT = "America/Yellowknife" = 19 Jul 2016 03:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.407 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Antarctica/Casey" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.408 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Antarctica/Davis" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.408 da[3702:334577] GMT+10 = "Antarctica/DumontDUrville" = 19 Jul 2016 19:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.409 da[3702:334577] GMT+11 = "Antarctica/Macquarie" = 19 Jul 2016 20:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.409 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Antarctica/Mawson" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.409 da[3702:334577] GMT+12 = "Antarctica/McMurdo" = 19 Jul 2016 21:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.410 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "Antarctica/Palmer" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.410 da[3702:334577] GMT-3 = "Antarctica/Rothera" = 19 Jul 2016 06:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.411 da[3702:334577] GMT+12 = "Antarctica/South_Pole" = 19 Jul 2016 21:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.411 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Antarctica/Syowa" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.412 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Antarctica/Troll" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.418 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Antarctica/Vostok" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.418 da[3702:334577] GMT+2 = "Arctic/Longyearbyen" = 19 Jul 2016 11:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.419 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Aden" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.419 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Almaty" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.420 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Amman" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.420 da[3702:334577] GMT+12 = "Asia/Anadyr" = 19 Jul 2016 21:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.420 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Aqtau" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.421 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Aqtobe" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.421 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Ashgabat" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.422 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Baghdad" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.422 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Bahrain" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.422 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Baku" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.423 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Bangkok" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.443 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Beirut" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.444 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Bishkek" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.444 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Brunei" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.444 da[3702:334577] GMT+9 = "Asia/Chita" = 19 Jul 2016 18:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.445 da[3702:334577] GMT+9 = "Asia/Choibalsan" = 19 Jul 2016 18:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.445 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Chongqing" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.446 da[3702:334577] GMT+5:30 = "Asia/Colombo" = 19 Jul 2016 14:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.446 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Damascus" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.447 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Dhaka" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.447 da[3702:334577] GMT+9 = "Asia/Dili" = 19 Jul 2016 18:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.448 da[3702:334577] GMT+4 = "Asia/Dubai" = 19 Jul 2016 13:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.448 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Dushanbe" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.449 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Gaza" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.449 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Harbin" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.449 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Hebron" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.450 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.450 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Hong_Kong" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.451 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Hovd" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.451 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Irkutsk" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.452 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Jakarta" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.452 da[3702:334577] GMT+9 = "Asia/Jayapura" = 19 Jul 2016 18:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.453 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Jerusalem" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.453 da[3702:334577] GMT+4:30 = "Asia/Kabul" = 19 Jul 2016 13:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.454 da[3702:334577] GMT+12 = "Asia/Kamchatka" = 19 Jul 2016 21:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.454 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Karachi" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.455 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Kashgar" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.455 da[3702:334577] GMT+5:45 = "Asia/Kathmandu" = 19 Jul 2016 15:01
2016-07-19 14:46:18.456 da[3702:334577] GMT+5:45 = "Asia/Katmandu" = 19 Jul 2016 15:01
2016-07-19 14:46:18.456 da[3702:334577] GMT+9 = "Asia/Khandyga" = 19 Jul 2016 18:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.457 da[3702:334577] GMT+5:30 = "Asia/Kolkata" = 19 Jul 2016 14:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.457 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Krasnoyarsk" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.458 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Kuala_Lumpur" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.458 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Kuching" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.458 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Kuwait" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.459 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Macau" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.459 da[3702:334577] GMT+10 = "Asia/Magadan" = 19 Jul 2016 19:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.460 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Makassar" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.460 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Manila" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.461 da[3702:334577] GMT+4 = "Asia/Muscat" = 19 Jul 2016 13:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.461 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Nicosia" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.462 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Novokuznetsk" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.462 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Novosibirsk" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.462 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Omsk" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.463 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Oral" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.463 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Phnom_Penh" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.464 da[3702:334577] GMT+7 = "Asia/Pontianak" = 19 Jul 2016 16:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.464 da[3702:334577] GMT+8:30 = "Asia/Pyongyang" = 19 Jul 2016 17:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.465 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Qatar" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.465 da[3702:334577] GMT+6 = "Asia/Qyzylorda" = 19 Jul 2016 15:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.466 da[3702:334577] GMT+6:30 = "Asia/Rangoon" = 19 Jul 2016 15:46
2016-07-19 14:46:18.466 da[3702:334577] GMT+3 = "Asia/Riyadh" = 19 Jul 2016 12:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.466 da[3702:334577] GMT+10 = "Asia/Sakhalin" = 19 Jul 2016 19:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.467 da[3702:334577] GMT+5 = "Asia/Samarkand" = 19 Jul 2016 14:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.467 da[3702:334577] GMT+9 = "Asia/Seoul" = 19 Jul 2016 18:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.468 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Shanghai" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
2016-07-19 14:46:18.468 da[3702:334577] GMT+8 = "Asia/Singapore" = 19 Jul 2016 17:16
```

Comment: But I want only one country time and that should be user country.
How can I get that?

Comment: you can get device time zone by using NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

Comment: By using NSDateFormatter convert date to currentTimeZone which is deviceLocalTimeZone

Comment: So I have to do like this?
    NSTimeZone *tz = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    [f setTimeZone:tz];

Answer (score 1):

I tried converting INDIAN time to other countries local time.I got the solution

```
NSString *strDate = @"19-07-2016";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *dateStr = [dateFormat dateFromString:strDate];
NSLog(@"The UTC format date is - %@",dateStr);

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSString *strLocalDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateStr];
NSLog(@"The Local date is - %@",strLocalDate);
```

The Printed Result is

```
The UTC format date is - 2016-07-19 00:00:00 +0000
The Local date is - 2016-07-19 05:30:00
```

[Getting Time based on Local Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c)

[Convert to UTC to Local Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564769/convert-utc-to-local-time-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
-(NSString *)getUTCFormateDate:(NSDate *)serverDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:serverDate];
    return dateString;
}
-(NSString *)getLocalDateTimeFromUTC:(NSString *)strDate
{
    NSDateFormatter *dtFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dtFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [dtFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSDate *aDate = [dtFormat dateFromString:strDate];

    [dtFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [dtFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    return [dtFormat stringFromDate:aDate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gives Date in UTC
NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// Timezone For India
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Asia/Kolkata"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remember two things:

1. Dates in IOS are "*immutable, representing an invariant time interval relative to an absolute reference date (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 2001)*" ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/descriptionWithLocale:)).  Its internal representation is always relative to that UTC point in time regardless of where on earth the device is.
2. Date formatters default to the user's locale ([ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)).   That means, as long as the user's device has the correct time and time zone in Settings, you don't need to do anything extra to convert the time to the local format and zone.

So, what you should do is convert India to UTC before assigning the value to an NSDate and IOS will take care of the rest.