# iOS Convert UTC date of NSDate to Localtime fo local notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime, uilocalnotification

I'm having trouble converting NSDate *date* to local DateTime. I'm using Local Notifications and my *fireDate* property is ok except UTC component in my date.

This is NSDate date and converted date to my local timezone

[image]

This is my conversion code as found here [Convert UTC NSDate to local Timezone Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c)

```
NSDate *someDateInUTC = [NSDate date];
NSTimeInterval timeZoneSeconds = [[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
NSDate *dateInLocalTimezone = [someDateInUTC dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeZoneSeconds];
```

I'm adding five seconds to my time component so this is my fireDate:

[image]

I'm using push notifications and when the user is somewhere in the app, I want to present him local notification from my push notification. This code is in my `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method. I've implemented method for local notifications:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  UIApplicationState applicationState = application.applicationState;
  if (applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
      [application presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
  }
}
```

I'm thinking that this UTC component in my *dateInLocalTimezone* is causing my trouble but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I don't follow.  What "trouble" are you having?  Where does that date/time come from in the first place?

Comment: Usually you don't need to do nothing with time zone, NSDate is always at 0000 and everything should work fine. I your case I don't sse any need of messing with time zones

Comment: This UTC at the end is causing me trouble and I want to show local notification after 5 seconds. I need to have time interval in my fireDate

Comment: @Andrea Ok, I have tried as you said it, it goes to didReceiveLocalNotification. But now it is just not showing as banner.

Comment: So you're saying you are having trouble creating the `NSDate` necessary to define when a local notification should be fired?  In which case `NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:numSeconds]` will work.

Comment: @Flipper I don't think that it has to deal with date timezone issue. It seems a different problem.

Comment: @Andrea Yes you are right. I've managed as you said. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i read your question. and i have then below example for you.

here i am converting Local time to UTC Time.

```
    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    fmt.dateFormat = @"LLL d, yyyy - HH:mm:ss zzz";
    NSDate *utc = [fmt dateFromString:@"June 14, 2012 - 01:00:00 UTC"];
    fmt.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    NSString *local = [fmt stringFromDate:utc];
    NSLog(@"%@", local);
```