# iOS CloudKit CKRecord modificationDate

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Can someone help me to understand?

I am in France...

My app have modified a record at 4.45 PM and when I request for the record (after relaunch), the modicationDate give me the date with one hour offset:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The debugger is logging the date in UTC time (note the +0000 timezone). There are countless existing discussion about dates appearing to be incorrect due to users misunderstanding the output of logging dates. tl;dr - they are the same date, there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean the date will be right on production? How can I check this?

Comment: Well it depends on what are you doing with the date, are you showing it to the user. To check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c.

Comment: The date is correct now in development and it will be correct in production.

Comment: Not showing date to the user, just want to update the application datas if iCloud date is more recent.  I have never seen these offset dates for files attributes for example or [NSDate date] or for files date on my server. What I am missing? I launch my application on my device.

Comment: maady, you are right, thanks!