# Compare NSDates across timezones

Tags: objective-c, timezone, nsdate

I'd like to compare and filter NSDates to determine whether there are any for today regarding the users current timezone.

Let's say I've a user located in Los Angeles (UTC-8 hours) and the following dates:

```
TargetDate
UTC:        2 pm (14:00) - 12. Feb 2017
LocalTime: 10 pm (22:00) - 12. Feb 2017

Now
UTC:       10 pm (22:00) - 11. Feb 2017   // Change of date!
LocalTime:  6 pm (06:00) - 12. Feb 2017

Today
UTC:       00 am (00:00) - 11. Feb 2017   // Begin of today

Tomorrow 
UTC:       00 am (00:00) - 12. Feb 2017
```

In the next step I'd like to compare the TargetDate, Today and Tomorrow to determine, if the TargetDate is between Today and Tomorrow. This is where the problem is. When I compare the dates I receive an answer that it is of course not between these dates.

```
+ (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending)
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

What I can do, is to convert the UTC date, `TargetDate`, to the local timezone but I'm very confused whether this is the best solution. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7739612/3191334) it's mentioned that you shouldn't do this because it confuses the whole problem.

Does anyone has an idea, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Your example data is bad.  LocalTime should be 8 hours *behind* UTC, not *ahead*...

Comment: Okay yes I mixed it up, it's the other way around for LA - HongKong would match.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is actually here:

```
Today
UTC:       00 am (00:00) - 11. Feb 2017   // Begin of today

Tomorrow 
UTC:       00 am (00:00) - 12. Feb 2017
```

You're deciding that the "day" is the UTC day.  Instead, you need to determine the day in the target time zone.

```
Today
LocalTime: 00 am (00:00) - 11. Feb 2017   // Begin of today
UTC:       08 am (08:00) - 11. Feb 2017   // Equivalent UTC

Tomorrow 
LocalTime: 00 am (00:00) - 12. Feb 2017   // Begin of tomorrow
UTC:       08 am (08:00) - 12. Feb 2017   // Equivalent UTC
```

Do keep in mind a few other things:

- Compare with half-open intervals:  `StartOfToday <= SomePointToday < StartOfTomorrow` (inclusive start, exclusive end).
- `America/Los_Angeles` is not always UTC-8.  It switches to UTC-7 during daylight saving time.
- Not every day starts at midnight.  For example, `America/Sao_Paulo` on 2016-10-16 started at 01:00.  The 00:00 hour was skipped for DST.
- If you just care about some point on that day, rather than the *entire* day, compare at 12:00 noon, rather than at 00:00 midnight.  It avoids the DST problem.

Comment: Thanks! So do you suggest to actually convert the date `Now` to the local timezone in order to determine the correct local date (`Today`and `Tomorrow`)? I'd like to summarise your answer into some example code.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I'd give you code, but while I do timezones in many languages, ObjectiveC isn't one of them. ;)